# How do I delete multiple column variables in SAS which just state "Null" but are not blank?

Tags: sas

How do I delete multiple column variables in SAS which just state "Null" but are not blank? I have created the following table;

```
DATA test;
INPUT name$ favourite_food$ occupation$ favourite_sport$;
CARDS;
John Null Nurse Null 
Michelle Null Lawyer Null
Peter Null Teacher Null 
Kai Null Doctor Null 
run;
```

Since the columns with Null values are not blank I am unsure of how to delete those columns. I do not need them for my analysis.

Also I know I can use the drop command to drop columns. However when I have around 90 variables is there a more effecient way to drop multiple "Null" variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options for this case.

1st, use the keep.
The keep function keeps the variable you want, so if you already know what the variables are other than NULL, just put in the keep, example:

DATA test(keep = favorite_food occupation);

```
INPUT name$ favourite_food$ occupation$ favourite_sport$;
CARDS;
John Null Nurse Null 
Michelle Null Lawyer Null
Peter Null Teacher Null 
Kai Null Doctor Null
```

run;

If you know favorite_food and occupation is not NULL.

2nd, use the delete function exemple:

DATA test;

```
INPUT name$ favourite_food$ occupation$ favourite_sport$;
CARDS;
   if name eq NULL then delete;
```

run;

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

The `nlevels` option in `proc freq` returns the number of distinct values in each column.  Therefore any columns where all values are the same will have an nlevel value of 1.

Providing you are confident that this rule will only apply to 'Null' columns, then you can use this method (i.e. there are at least 2 distinct values of name, occupation etc).

The `nlevel` value is not automatically included in the output table within `proc freq`, so you need to use `ods output` to get the column names into a table.  Then you can assign them to a macro variable, to be used in a `drop` statement in whatever analysis procedure you're using.  Or you could delete them as you've asked, in a data step. (I generally prefer the former option, just in case valid data is deleted erroneously).

```
DATA test;
INPUT name$ favourite_food$ occupation$ favourite_sport$;
CARDS;
John Null Nurse Null 
Michelle Null Lawyer Null
Peter Null Teacher Null 
Kai Null Doctor Null 
run;

/* identify columns with only 1 distinct value and output to a table */
ods output nlevels = distinct_values (where=(nlevels=1));
proc freq data=test nlevels;
run;

/* store column names in macro variable */
proc sql noprint;
select tablevar into :drop_cols separated by ' '
from distinct_values;
quit;

%put &drop_cols;

/* exclude columns from analysis */
proc freq data=test (drop=&drop_cols.);
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

A full scan of the data is required to examine all the values in all the columns.  During the scan, the occurrence of a value other than `"Null"` will exclude that column as a drop candidate.

You can use a temporary array to track what the character column names are, and another array set to `_CHARACTER_` so those columns can be iterated over in each row.  The process will construct a list of columns that can be dropped according to your criteria -- that list is placed in the macro symbol table and can be used in subsequent code, to either rewrite the data with-out those columns, or to simply drop them during processing using a data set option.

```
DATA test;
INPUT name$ favourite_food$ occupation$ favourite_sport$;
CARDS;
John Null Nurse Null 
Michelle Null Lawyer Null
Peter Null Teacher Null 
Kai Null Doctor Null 
Zonker Null Null Null
run;

%let DROP_VARS=;

data _null_;
  set test end=end;

  array char_vars _CHARACTER_;               * for iterating over values;
  array null_vars (1000) $32 _temporary_ ;   * for tracking column names;

  * populate column name tracking array;
  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    do index = 1 to dim(char_vars);
      null_vars(index) = vname(char_vars(index));
    end;
  end;

  * scan each row, iterating over character variables;
  * remove a column name from drop consideration when non "Null" occurs;
  do index = 1 to dim(char_vars);
    if not missing(null_vars(index)) then
      if char_vars(index) ne "Null" then
        null_vars(index) = '';
  end;

  * place space separated list of columns containing only "Null" in macro symbol table;
  if end then
    call symput('DROP_VARS', catx(' ', of null_vars(*)));
run;

* use macro variable as desired;

%put NOTE: &=DROP_VARS;

proc print data=test(drop=&DROP_VARS);
  title "Non-null columns of TEST";
run;

data TEST2(label="Copy of Test, excluding null columns");
  set TEST;
  drop &DROP_VARS;
run;
```

There are many other SAS ways to code a solution to *drop columns having all the same value* -- search them up !

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to do this using sql in a macro. Detailed comments are added.
 @longfish solution is simple and very effective.

```
   %macro abc;
/* picking up the variables on which Null check is needed*/
   proc sql;
    /*finding total number of obervations*/
      select count(*) into :cnt from test;
       select name into :name separated by '|' from dictionary.columns
            where upcase(memname) = 'TEST'
            and lowcase(name) like '%favourite_%';

    /*creting temporary table to hold the values which should be dropped*/
    create table temptable(col char(50),val num);;

    /* looping through variables for which null check is needed*/
    %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&name, |));
        %let col_val =%scan(&name,&i,|);

        /* total obervations minus count for variables with null values gives 0
        indicates that all are null values and are inseted in a temptable*/
proc sql;
    insert into temptable
        select col, val from
        (select "&col_val" as col , &cnt- count(&col_val) as val
            from test
                where &col_val = "Null")
                where val = 0;
    %end;

    /*picking up all the columns to be dropped*/
proc sql;
    select col into  :drop_columns separated by ' '
        from temptable;
    %put &drop_columns;

    /* dropping the columns*/
data want;
    set test(drop=&drop_columns);
run;

%mend;

%abc;
```